# A good word for additions to a written work that is already published

Tags: nouns

Let's say I have already published a book. Now, on the website for this book, I want to post additional documents, numbered like 1, 2, .... What word is best to use to describe each of these documents?

Would "Addendum" work? Like "Addendum 1", "Addendum 2", or is Addendum more for things at the end of the book itself?

Feel free to suggest other words. I suppose "Supplement" is another alternative.

Comment: They're both OK. So's "Appendix". There's no real distinction between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your ideas, "[addendum](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addendum)" and "[supplement](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplement)", are perfect.

> […] is Addendum more for things at the end of the book itself?

It can be, but its original and core meaning is "thing to be added", so it somewhat implies that something *should* have been part of the original work. As a result, it's more often used for things that *aren't* part of the original work. (This implication has decreased over time, so I wouldn't consider it wrong to include an "addendum" at the end of a work, but it's still 100% absolutely correct to use "addendum" to refer to something completely separate that adds to a work.)

Answer (score 2):

The already-mentioned  *[addendum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addendum#Noun)* (“Something to be added; especially text added as an appendix or supplement to a document”) and  *[supplement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supplement#Noun)* (“An extension to a document or publication that adds information, corrects errors or brings up to date”) may serve.  I'm inclined against  *[appendix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendix#Noun)* (“...a text added to the end of a book or an article, containing information that is important to but is not the main idea of the main text”); I think that in practice appendices usually are mentioned already in the main text, (and are used to explain details of less-general interest) vs being an addendum or supplement that may be of general interest.

If the web-page add-ons are primarily corrections, you may refer to them as  *[errata](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/errata#Noun)* (“An added page in a printed work where errors which are discovered after printing and their corrections are listed; corrigenda”) or  *[corrigenda](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corrigenda)* (“A list of errors in a printed work as a separate page of corrections, known as an errata page”) or possibly *[corrigendum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corrigendum#Noun)*.